# Prevent contenteditable auto-focus on Enter keypress on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div on which I control the behavior of some keys. In particular, I have this:

```
$('#my_contenteditable').on('keydown', function(e) {
  // Some code...
  if (e.key == 'Enter') {
    $(this).blur();
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  // Some more code...
});
```

But after I blured the element, when I press Enter again, Chrome wants to re-focus it.

[JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/uff3M/558/)

Can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.target.blur()
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('#my_contenteditable').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.key == 'Enter') {
    $(this).attr("contenteditable","false");

  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to remove contenteditable though. Just lose focus on the element. But the user must be able to edit it again after that.

Comment: In the end, your answer lead me to the solution. In fact, removing `contenteditable` is cool. I just have to add it again on the `click` event. Don't know how this plays with accessibility though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Prakhar Mathur's answer :

```
$('#my_contenteditable').on('click', function() {
  $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
});
$('#my_contenteditable').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.key == 'Enter') {
    $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
});
```